# why doesnt this double loop work?

Tags: python

First of all, here's the code:

```
def check_sudoku(n):
    d=len(n)
    i=0
    s=1
    while i<d:
        print "i=",i
        while s<d:
            print "s=",s
            if n[0][i]==n[s][i]:
                return False
            s=s+1
            i=i+1
         return True
```

what I want to do is that after the value of `s` changes from `1` to `d`, then it loops again and the value of `i` changes.
But in my code the value of `i` is not changing at all.

Just to be clear of what I want to do,
say

```
n =[[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,3],
    [3,1,2,3],
    [4,4,4,4]]
```

i want the following to happen:

- first it should check for

  ```
  n[0][0]==n[1][0]
  n[0][0]==n[2][0]
  n[0][0]==n[3][0]
  ```

  after that value of `i` should increase by 1
- then it should go like this:

  ```
  n[0][1]==n[1][1]
  n[0][1]==n[2][1]
  n[0][1]==n[3][1]
  ```

after this value of `i` will increase again and this same loop will run.

This is not happening and I am not sure why.
Please tell me what changes I should make to make it run the way I want to.

Comment: Your indentation was messed up, and your last line (`return True`) will exit the outer loop early. Could you check if that shouldn't be dedented? Currently it'll actually give a indentation exception as it has one space more indentation than the inner while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop increments `s` until it is greater than `d`, but you never set it back to `1`. Also, with your current indentation, you also increment `i` in the inner loop, so it'll reach `d` inside the inner loop causing the *outer* loop to only be run once too.

So, if `d` is 4, your values will go:

```
i = 0, s = 1
i = 1, s = 2
i = 2, s = 3
# exit inner loop
return True
```

You'd be much better off using `for` loops using [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range), avoiding your mistakes altogether:

```
def check_sudoku(n):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for s in range(1, len(n)):
            if n[0][i]==n[s][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

With `range` the inner loop will always start at `1`, range through to `len(n)` every time without explicit resets needed.

If you use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) you can collapse the whole test into one line:

```
def check_sudoku(n):
    return not any(n[0][i] == n[s][i] for i in range(len(n)) for s in range(1, len(n)))
```

Comment: I agree this solution is better, but the OP asked why his solution wasn't working. The answer to which is what @unwind said.

Comment: @MikeVella: actually, it goes a bit further than what unwind said; updated my answer to point out more problems (and why you'd want to use for loops then is even more obvious). I rather teach how to fish than just help catch the one..

Comment: Thanks Martijn,
your explanation about how "i" was already being incremented in the inner loop, really made it clear to me why it wasn't working the way I wanted it to.
ofcourse, I would love a better way to do this, but I just wanted to get my concept clear about this loop and why it wasn't working.
I dont want to make the same mistakes in the future and that's why wanted to get it all clear in my mind, before moving on to a better way.
As for the indentation part, it seems like I keep making these sort of mistakes. would love some advice about indentations.

Comment: Use a good editor, one that auto-indents for you. Configure it to use spaces, not tabs, set to 4 spaces. I use Sublime Text 2 myself. Perhaps use tools like `pyflakes`; my editor has a plugin that automates that for me (I see inline warnings, plugin is called SublimeLinter).

Answer (score 3):

You don't reset `s` in the outer loop, so the inner loop will only execute once. After that, `s < d` will never be true again.

Answer (score 1):

Further to unwind's answer, this is the modified code in a way that should work. I've changed the whitespace in the code and the operators in a way which most Python programmers will consider more conventional.

```
def check_sudoku(n):
    d = len(n)
    i = 0
    s = 1

    while i < d:
        print "i=",i
        while s < d:
            print "s=",s
            if n[0][i] == n[s][i]:
                return False
            s += 1
        i += 1
        s = 1
    return True 

n =[[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,3],
    [3,1,2,3],
    [4,4,4,4]]

check_sudoku(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should move the statement i=i+1 over the second loop follow as:

```
def check_sudoku(n):
d=len(n)
i=0
s=1
while i<d:
    print "i=",i
    while s<d:
        print "s=",s
        if n[0][i]==n[s][i]:
            return False
        s=s+1
    i=i+1
    return True
```

Comment: Like the OP, you have your indentation messed up. Now the function will return True after one run through the outer loop.

Comment: Moreover, you do not reset `s`, so it'll still only be executed once.